# Union All in SQL server with Order By For All Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two table `TABLE_A` and `TABLE_B`, and I am using `Union All` to get records with `Order By` with the help of following in SQL server 2008

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
 (
   SELECT *, 1 sortby FROM TABLE_A 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT *, 2 sortby FROM TABLE_B
  ) Temp
ORDER   BY sortby
```

but the problem is above statement is `Order By` only data from `Table_A`, and `Table_B` is not with `Order By`, I want to add Order By condition on both tables, data should be come Assending from TABLE_A first then after Assending from TABLE_B.

How to do this.

Comment: I don't have 2008 here. I'd think that just `SELECT *, 1 sortby FROM TABLE_A UNION ALL SELECT *, 2 sortby FROM TABLE_B ORDER BY sortby` would work. (lose the outer select and keep the order by line) However, I'm not a fan of `SELECT *`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add the other column you want to sort by in the `order` clause

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
 (
   SELECT *, 1 sortby FROM TABLE_A 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT *, 2 sortby FROM TABLE_B
  ) Temp
ORDER BY sortby, other_column_of_result
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do like this

```
SELECT  * 
FROM 
 (
   SELECT *, 1 firstsortby, 2 secondsortby FROM TABLE_A 
   UNION ALL 
   SELECT *, 2 firstsortby, 1 secondsortby FROM TABLE_B
  ) Temp
ORDER BY firstsortby, secondsortby
```